# How to add quotes to either end of a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

> 2014-02-23

and I want to add quotes to either end.

> "2014-02-23"

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The best ? What's wrong with `'"'+s+'"'` ?

Comment: Could you start with `Why I want to wrap double quotes around my date`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in every tutorial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest :

```
'"'+s+'"'
```

The jsonest (only if your string doesn't contain quotes) :

```
JSON.stringify(s)
```

The regexest :

```
s.replace(/^|$/g,'"')
```

The best ? Choose your own.

Comment: I think you meant "bestest".

Comment: @Andy I'm unsure. I don't know English very well, I'm on SO in an effort to learn it.

Comment: For consideration: The arrayiest: `['"', s, '"'].join('');`

Comment: the JSONest one doesn't qualify. It also escapes existing quotes (and backslashes)

Comment: The jQueriest: `$('<b/>').html('My String').append('"').prepend('"').text()`

Comment: @Cerbrus does that actually work? Also, use `text` rather than `html`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: It seems to return a string with as contents: `"My String"`